# Optimal Table may change in LPP

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex-method

If we solve a LPP with let's say 2 constraints with all slack starting variables with non negative right hand side. We get the optimal table. Now suppose we change the constraint coefficient of a basic variable and compute the optima using post optimality analysis using a combination of dual simplex and simplex method. My question is will the optimal table be different to what we would have got had we started the question all over again by the new constrain? Actually, my point of optima and solution matches, but there is a entry in my final optimal table that does not match with the optimal table of problem if I had solved it from scratch. Can somebody explain?

Comment: It depends on how much the constraint coefficient has been changed.

Comment: If a single entry does not match, that's most likely to be a calculation error. There are ways to end up getting some amount of variety in the optimal tableau, but generally they will be *more* different than that. (But seeing more details would probably help diagnose the issue.)